# cursor initialization error [android]

Tags: android, android-cursor

```
    public HashMap<String,String> getUserDetails(){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
    System.out.println("select query:"+selectQuery);
    System.out.println("entering into hashmap");

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    System.out.println("cursor count is");
    System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        System.out.println("enter into if of hashmap");
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("country", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("state", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("city", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("registered_on", cursor.getString(8));
      }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return user
    return user;
}
```

error:couldn't read row 0, col 8 from CursorWindow. make sure the Cursor is initialized correclty before accessing data from it.

not able to fetch any data from SQLiteDatabase

thanks

Comment: change position from (1-8) to (0-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Cursor, column index is 0 based.

That is if you want to fetch data from 1st column then you should use `cursor.getString(0)` instead of `cursor.getString(1)`

So you need to replace

```
 if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        System.out.println("enter into if of hashmap");
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("country", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("state", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("city", cursor.getString(7));
        user.put("registered_on", cursor.getString(8));
      }
```

by following code....

```
 if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        System.out.println("enter into if of hashmap");
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(0));
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("country", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("state", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("city", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("registered_on", cursor.getString(7));
      }
```

In your code its trying to fetch data from 9th column which does not exists.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code: **use cursor.getString(0) instead of cursor.getString(1)**

```
public HashMap<String,String> getUserDetails(){
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
System.out.println("select query:"+selectQuery);
System.out.println("entering into hashmap");

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
 do
 {
  HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
  user.put("username", cursor.getString(0));
    user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
    user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
    user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(3));
    user.put("country", cursor.getString(4));
    user.put("state", cursor.getString(5));
    user.put("city", cursor.getString(6));
    user.put("registered_on", cursor.getString(7));
     wordList.add(user);
  }while(cursor.moveToNext);
    return wordList
}
  else
     {
       System.out.println("No data found");
       return null;
     }
  }
```

we can display data using this code.

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result;
 result= Objectname.getdetails();
 for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
    {
         HashMap<String,String> content = new HashMap<String, String>();
         content = result.get(i);
               String username=content.get("username").toString();
                String name=content.get("name").toString();
                String email=content.get("email").toString();
                String uid=content.get("user_id").toString();
                String country=content.get("country").toString();
                String state=content.get("state").toString();
                String city=content.get("city").toString();
                String reg=content.get("registered_on").toString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your index of cursor which is starting from 1.. start from 0 to 7. and it will work like below:

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        user.put("username", cursor.getString(0));
        user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
        user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
        user.put("user_id", cursor.getString(3));
        user.put("country", cursor.getString(4));
        user.put("state", cursor.getString(5));
        user.put("city", cursor.getString(6));
        user.put("registered_on", cursor.getString(7));
      }
```